# Rectangular arrays of fixed size at runtime

Tags: vb.net, arrays

In languages like C++ and Java, it is possible to declare an array of an arbitrary size and then give it a specific size later in the code.

Example (Java):

```
int[][] table;
//some code goes here
//variables sizeX and sizeY are assigned values
table = new int[sizeX][sizeY];
```

Is there a way to do the same in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With vanilla arrays you can;

```
Dim table(,) As integer    
...
ReDim table(sizeX, sizeY)
...
table(1, 3) = 42
```